Generate as short as possible boolean formula from a given truth table
Given a truth table, maybe 3-vars, 5-vars or even 10-vars, i can write its formula in DNF or CNF, and simplify it using K-Map or Quine-McCluskey algorithm. But it is based on {NOT, AND, OR}. Now the question is, how can i write a shorter formula from the truth table, based on {NOT, AND, OR, XOR, IMPLY, XNOR}?
Since this question is a math problem i previously asked on Mathematics Stack Exchange, I post it here to ask how I can write a program in Python to solve it.
I've already used PyEDA to generate a long formula from a given truth table, and use SymPy to simplify it. However, it's still complex using only {NOT, AND, OR} operators. for example, given a 10-vars truth table, it results in a formula of 3000 characters.
I was expecting to find a method to generate a shorter formula from the existed formula, or the given truth table, using {NOT, AND, OR, XOR, IMPLY, XNOR}.

Although I don't do much of this, I suspect that SymPy SOPForm might be what you are looking for, perhaps followed up with a call to simplify_logic. Bot functions are in sympy/logic/boolalg. Here is the docstring of the former:
    The SOPform function uses simplified_pairs and a redundant group-
    eliminating algorithm to convert the list of all input combos that
    generate '1' (the minterms) into the smallest sum-of-products form.

    The variables must be given as the first argument.

    Return a logical :py:class:`~.Or` function (i.e., the "sum of products" or
    "SOP" form) that gives the desired outcome. If there are inputs that can
    be ignored, pass them as a list, too.

    The result will be one of the (perhaps many) functions that satisfy
    the conditions.

    Examples
    ========

    >>> from sympy.logic import SOPform
    >>> from sympy import symbols
    >>> w, x, y, z = symbols('w x y z')
    >>> minterms = [[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1],
    ...             [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
    >>> dontcares = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1]]
    >>> SOPform([w, x, y, z], minterms, dontcares)
    (y & z) | (~w & ~x)

